Honda Tiller Dies Under Load
Two weeks ago, I purchased a new Honda TG110 tiller. I tested it out, tilled about 20 feet of my yard and based on that experiment, assumed it was working. I ordered sod for delivery. Yesterday I went to go and till the area I want to lay the sod and discovered that my tiller dies every time I open the throttle. Most of my searches on the internet are for maintenance on 10 year old models. I tried changing out the fuel. I am now using 92 Octane pure gasoline made for four stroke engines. The engine is a Honda GX25. I am pretty frustrated. Appreciate any help you can offer.

Manual choke? Since they haven't been on cars for a few decades, folks tend to forget they need to be opened once the motor starts and warms up a bit. Or that the motor needs to warm up a bit to run well.

Sounds like it should still be under warranty...

100% a warranty issue. If you still want to pursue the cause beyond that, I'd recommend [mechanics.se] where any internal combustion engine is on topic.

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [mechanics.se]

Is the fuel valve open all the way? Sounds lean.

@isherwood diagnosing farm equipment in two suggestive words from a vast distance.   You hopefully have a few days scruff, standing alone with the sun setting behind you, issuing a hoarsy "Sounds lean"?

There's no way to know without testing the tiller in person, but what you describe sounds like a clogged carb. Honda engines are known to get clogged easily when using old fuel or fuel with ethanol -- I don't know the reason why. But I used to take my Honda engines to the shop for carb cleaning every few years, until I got religious about using no-ethanol fresh fuel, and clearing the engine before storage. My other engines do well with regular fuel, so to me it seems like a Honda issue. Honda engines are otherwise great. Good luck

Dirty carb?  It's two weeks out of the box.
